# Evaluate $ \sum\limits_{j \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}} {n \choose r+kj}$ where $n,k$ are fixed

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

> Is there a general way/technique to evaluate $ \sum\limits_{j \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}} {n \choose r+kj}$ in terms of $r$, where we consider $n$ and $k$ fixed natural numbers and $n > k$? (here, we consider ${a \choose b}=0$ if $b>a$)

In other words, I want the sum of the binomial coefficients ${n \choose i}$ where $i$ is less than or equal to $n$ and belongs to the arithmetic progression $r,r+k,r+2k,..., $ etc.

If $r=0$, we're looking for the sum of the binomial coefficients ${n \choose i}$ such that $k|i$, i.e., we want to evaluate the sum ${n \choose 0}+{n \choose k}+{n \choose 2k}+...$, which can be done using the roots of unity filter technique (link [here](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/blog/24380)) for the sum of the coefficients $a_i$ of a polynomial $f$ such that $k|i$ (in this case $f$ would be the polynomial $(1+x)^n$)

Any help? Thank you!

Comment: I would think that similar techniques with roots of unity will work, if $r<k$. In other words, if you take the full coset of remainders modulo $k$. But in general this looks scary. Consider the case with $k=1$, when you would just be summing up the binomial coefficients from some point on. I think that the best we can say (for large $n$) is to approximate the binomial distribution with normal distribution and go from there. I may be wrong though.